# ChromeCast issue with Play Ready Smooth Streaming

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, drm, azure-media-services, playready

I'm using Azure Media Services to upload, encode and encrypt videos into PlayReady smooth streaming format. I'm using the Play Ready test server located at : http://playready.directtaps.net/

During the encoding process, I'm using licenseAcquisitionUrl for PlayReady as : http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx

All the other things are configured and set as described at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn189154.aspx

PlayReady Smooth Stream : http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest

The above stream works on : http://smf.cloudapp.net/healthmonitor (no option of setting up license acquisition url)

The above stream does not work on : http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/ even after setting/removing License Acquisition Url.

Also, I'm using ChromeCast to cast these streams according to the Receiver Sample : https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM

The play ready stream does not seem to work on the above google cast example, and gives a "Fatal Error: code = 1" (I guess LOAD METADATA ERROR) , even after setting/removing License Acquisition Url.

The HLS stream encrypted with PlayReady as well as the MPEG DASH stream with PlayReady do not work at all on the ChromeCast Receiver Sample.

Please help!

EDIT : Adding Logs

```
[  0.306s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0002
 cast_receiver.js:18
### Application Loaded. Starting system. mpl.js:649
 [  0.339s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening message bus websocket
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.347s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.498s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.512s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IpcChannel opened
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.521s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"type":"opened"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.528s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.537s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Underlying message bus is open
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.541s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"ready\",\"statusText\":\"Ready to play\",\"activeNamespaces\":[\"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer\",\"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media\"],\"version\":\"2.0.0\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\"}"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.554s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender","data":"{\"type\":\"startheartbeat\",\"maxInactivity\":6000}"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.568s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"applicationId\":\"9E986387\",\"applicationName\":\"Custom Receiver with DRM\",\"launchingSenderId\":\"2:client-81798\",\"messagesVersion\":\"1.0\",\"sessionId\":\"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753\",\"type\":\"ready\",\"version\":\"1.0\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.579s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"applicationId":"9E986387","applicationName":"Custom Receiver with DRM","launchingSenderId":"2:client-81798","messagesVersion":"1.0","sessionId":"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753","type":"ready","version":"1.0"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.581s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  0.584s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager system ready event [[object Object]]
 cast_receiver.js:18
### Cast Receiver Manager is READY: {"type":"ready","C":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Sa":true,"data":{"id":"9E986387","name":"Custom Receiver with DRM","sessionId":"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753","namespaces":["urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer","urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media"],"launchingSenderId":"2:client-81798"}} mpl.js:202
 [  1.133s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"2:client-81798\",\"type\":\"senderconnected\",\"userAgent\":\"\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  1.135s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system, SystemSender]: {"senderId":"2:client-81798","type":"senderconnected","userAgent":""}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  1.137s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] CastReceiverManager message received: [object Object]
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  1.139s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [2:client-81798]
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  1.141s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer, 2:client-81798]
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [  1.143s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 2:client-81798]
 cast_receiver.js:18
### Cast Receiver Manager - Sender Connected : {"type":"senderconnected","C":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Sa":true,"data":"2:client-81798","senderId":"2:client-81798","userAgent":""} mpl.js:215
 [ 11.026s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"license\",\"value\":\"http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer","senderId":"2:client-81798"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 11.034s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer, 2:client-81798]: {"type":"license","value":"http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
### Message Bus - Media Message: {"type":"message","C":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Sa":true,"senderId":"2:client-81798","data":"{\"type\":\"license\",\"value\":\"http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx\"}"} mpl.js:268
### CUSTOM MESSAGE: {"type":"message","C":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Sa":true,"senderId":"2:client-81798","data":"{\"type\":\"license\",\"value\":\"http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx\"}"} mpl.js:271
{"type":"license","value":"http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx"} mpl.js:273
 [ 11.056s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"license\",\"value\":\"http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx\"}"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 12.220s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"LOAD\",\"requestId\":52887016,\"sessionId\":\"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753\",\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"video/mp4\"},\"autoplay\":true,\"currentTime\":0,\"customData\":{\"payload\":{\"title\":\"Big Buck Bunny\"}}}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"2:client-81798"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 12.225s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 2:client-81798]: {"type":"LOAD","requestId":52887016,"sessionId":"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753","media":{"contentId":"http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"video/mp4"},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"customData":{"payload":{"title":"Big Buck Bunny"}}}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 12.231s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] MediaManager message received [2:client-81798] {"type":"LOAD","requestId":52887016,"sessionId":"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753","media":{"contentId":"http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"video/mp4"},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"customData":{"payload":{"title":"Big Buck Bunny"}}}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 12.235s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Dispatching MediaManager load event
 cast_receiver.js:18
### Media Manager - LOAD: {"type":"load","C":false,"defaultPrevented":false,"Sa":true,"data":{"requestId":52887016,"sessionId":"5715726D-2985-E111-297B-7C6CB1A79753","media":{"contentId":"http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest","streamType":"buffered","contentType":"video/mp4"},"autoplay":true,"currentTime":0,"customData":{"payload":{"title":"Big Buck Bunny"}}},"senderId":"2:client-81798"} mpl.js:546
##### video/mp4 mpl.js:621
### Media Protocol Identified as Smooth Streaming mpl.js:632
 [ 12.094s] [cast.player.api.Player] version 0.4.0
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.101s] [cast.player.api.Player] revision 6
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.116s] [cast.player.api.Player] load 0
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.142s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.160s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.166s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest -1]
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest". media_player.js:51
 [ 12.196s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.237s] [cast.player.common] Audio codecPrivateData guess: 1210
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.251s] [cast.player.common] Audio codecPrivateData guess: 1210
 media_player.js:23
######### MEDIA ELEMENT LOAD START mpl.js:44
 [ 12.361s] [cast.player.api.Player] sourceopen
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.423s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 0: from undefined to 1740668
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.429s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: abort
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.467s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.476s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 0: seek 0
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.507s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=0) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.515s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=0) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.520s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=0) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.535s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 1: from undefined to 93593
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.544s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: abort
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.559s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.563s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] 1: seek 0
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.576s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…64c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=0) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.581s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…64c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=0) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.585s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…64c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=0) -1]
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…4c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=0))". media_player.js:51
 [ 12.644s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…64c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=0) 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.648s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onXhrSuccess_ 1: pending segment
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=0))". media_player.js:51
 [ 12.677s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=0) 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.685s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onXhrSuccess_ 0: pending segment
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.694s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.710s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onBufferReady 0: process pending
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.747s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.763s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.766s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onBufferReady 1: process pending
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.775s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.826s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeysManager] onNeedKey_: 1
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.832s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeySession] createSession
 media_player.js:23
 [ 12.844s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeysManager] onNeedKey_: 2
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.031s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Metadata loaded
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 13.046s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending broadcast status message
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 13.056s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"type\":\"MEDIA_STATUS\",\"status\":[{\"mediaSessionId\":1,\"playbackRate\":1,\"playerState\":\"BUFFERING\",\"currentTime\":0,\"supportedMediaCommands\":15,\"volume\":{\"level\":1,\"muted\":false},\"media\":{\"contentId\":\"http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest\",\"streamType\":\"buffered\",\"contentType\":\"video/mp4\",\"duration\":9.6826}}],\"requestId\":52887016}"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 12.889s] [cast.player.api.Player] loadedmetadata
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.048s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…ed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=20020000) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.057s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…ed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=20020000) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.061s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…ed8564c2119/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(1740668)/Fragments(video=20020000) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.087s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=20201360) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.106s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=20201360) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.114s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=20201360) -1]
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=20201360))". media_player.js:51
 [ 13.144s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=20201360) 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.153s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onXhrSuccess_ 1: pending segment
 media_player.js:23
######### MEDIA ELEMENT DATA LOADED mpl.js:48
{} mpl.js:90
 [ 13.369s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"video_bitrates\":[1740668,1416013,889057,682029,435390]}"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
 [ 13.376s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.mediaplayer","senderId":"*:*","data":"{\"audio_bitrates\":[53640]}"}
 cast_receiver.js:18
######### MEDIA ELEMENT CAN PLAY mpl.js:116
 [ 13.222s] [cast.player.api.Player] play
 media_player.js:23
######### MEDIA ELEMENT PLAYING mpl.js:126
 [ 13.349s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 0: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.360s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.365s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onBufferReady 1: process pending
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.370s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.410s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=40402721) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.418s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=40402721) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.427s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=40402721) -1]
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=40402721))". media_player.js:51
 [ 13.459s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=40402721) 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.463s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onXhrSuccess_ 1: pending segment
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.481s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.489s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onBufferReady 1: process pending
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.500s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.535s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager] 1: bitrate 2149525.703534414
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.548s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=60604081) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.552s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=60604081) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.569s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=60604081) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.607s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: updateend
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=60604081))". media_player.js:51
 [ 13.622s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=60604081) 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.633s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.642s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=80805442) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.646s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 30000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=80805442) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.651s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=80805442) -1]
 media_player.js:23
XHR finished loading: "http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=80805442))". media_player.js:51
 [ 13.677s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Request complete [GET http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c…/interview2.ism/QualityLevels(93593)/Fragments(AAC_und_ch2_96kbps=80805442) 200]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.681s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onXhrSuccess_ 1: pending segment
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.690s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.694s] [cast.player.core.SegmentManager] onBufferReady 1: process pending
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.698s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: append
 media_player.js:23
 [ 13.707s] [cast.player.core.SourceBufferManager] 1: updateend
 media_player.js:23
 [ 14.508s] [cast.player.core.MediaKeySession] onKeyMessage_
 media_player.js:23
 [ 14.519s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [POST http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 14.531s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 180000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [POST http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [ 14.536s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [POST http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/svc/rightsmanager.asmx -1]
 media_player.js:23
######### MEDIA ELEMENT ERROR [object Event] mpl.js:140
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON mpl.js:359
 [ 14.695s] [cast.player.api.Player] error
 media_player.js:23
### HOST ERROR - Fatal Error: code = 1 mpl.js:611
 [ 14.704s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload 0
```

Comment: There isn't any information about the error that you are getting when you try to use the stream so it is not possible to say much. One common issue is lack of CORS headers, have you taken care of that?

Comment: I'm not receiving any CORS based errors. And as such Windows Azure Media Services generates the CORS headers by itself.
Also, the stream plays on the smf.cloudapp.net/healthmonitor So its not an issue of CORS I suppose.

Comment: We don't see what error(s) you are getting so I can't make any further suggestions.

Comment: Could you please guide me as to how I can provide you with a detailed log which could help you?

Comment: It would be really helpful if someone gives this process a try and make it work!

Comment: You need to collect logs on the receiver. How to do that is described at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver under the section Debugging. You also mentioned it didn't work on  http://playready.directtaps.net/pr/doc/slee/ so it sounds to me there is an issue with your stream independently of the chromecast.

Comment: Also have a look at the network tab of the debug tools to see what the response for that request is.

Comment: The exception you are seeing states that the MediaElement had an issue with your stream, so you need to see what is the issue with your stream.

Comment: Did you enable CORS headers on the server that is serving the smooth streaming? I could not check it as the content is not there anymore on http://wamsstaticpoc.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6d32a54f-ba98-4b06-8c60-bed8564c2119/interview2.ism/manifest